# How do I build the jailbreak iPhone toolchain on Snow Leopard?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to build the toolchain for iphone on the snow leopard.I search on google and the answer is always for leopard.I replant it on snow leopard but there are some error.I can't build it.Does somebody had build it?

Comment: .... What? Why don't you just download the iPhone SDK for Snow Leopard? You don't need to build the toolchain... what are you talking about?

Comment: To build something like mobilesubstrate plugins

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try develop iPhone apps w/out certificate, just install iPhone SDK and follow this: http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2009/06/use-xcode-312-to-build-sdk-30-app-to-30.html

Comment: Snow leopard is impossibility at least I know.